Confocal microscope aligment
I’m using classic confocal microscope system. The laser wavelength is $405$ $nm$ and the objective is $80x$, $Na=0.75$, $\infty /0$. The pinhole diameter is $15 $ $\mu m$.
What should be the precision of setting the lens between output of the objective and the pinhole?
How accuracy of this setting change axial resolution?
